# C# Lazy property

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a Lazy property in my class:

```
private Lazy<ISmtpClient> SmtpClient
    {
        get
        {
            return new Lazy<ISmtpClient>(() => _objectCreator.Create<ISmtpClient>(), true);
        }
    }
```

Also a methode that uses this proptery:

```
public void SendEmail(MailMessage message)
    {
        SmtpClient.Value.ServerName = "testServer";
        SmtpClient.Value.Port = 25;

        SmtpClient.Value.Send(message);
    }
```

But in my SmtpClient, in Send(string message) methode are all the propteries that i initialized in the above SendEmail(MailMessage message) methode, null.

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using `Lazy<T>` wrong.

When using `Lazy<T>` you expose a property of the actual type and you have one `Lazy<T>` instance. You don't create a new one every time the property is accessed:

```
Lazy<ISmtpClient> _smtpClient =
    new Lazy<ISmtpClient>(() => _objectCreator.Create<MySmtpClient>(), true);

private ISmtpClient SmtpClient
{
    get
    {
        return _smtpClient.Value;
    }
}
```

Now, the first time the `SmtpClient` property is accessed, the object creator creates a new instance of `MySmtpClient`. This is returned. On subsequent calls, the same instance is returned.

The usage would be like this:

```
public void SendEmail(MailMessage message)
{
    SmtpClient.ServerName = "testServer";
    SmtpClient.Port = 25;

    SmtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i did post the wrong code of the lazy property, the actual code is like this:
    private Lazy<ISmtpClient> SmtpClient
        {
            get
            {
                return new Lazy<ISmtpClient>(() => _objectCreator.Create<ISmtpClient>(), true);
            }
        }

Is it stil not good?

Comment: @Djave: That's exactly the same as you had before.

Comment: The difference is _objectCreator.Create<ISmtpClient>() , instead of _objectCreator.Create<MySmtpClient>()

Comment: @Djave: Ah. Doesn't change the underlying problem I explained in my answer.

Comment: I tried what you suggested like this:
Lazy<ISmtpClient> _smtpClient =
    new Lazy<ISmtpClient>(() => _objectCreator.Create<ISmtpClient>(), true);

but still the same problem

private ISmtpClient SmtpClient
{
    get
    {
        return _smtpClient.Value;
    }
}

Comment: @Djave: That's not possible. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct. Just want to add a clarification on why your code doesn't work.

Every time you access `SmtpClient`, in your original code, a new `Lazy<ISmtpClient>` object is created, which is then initialized immediately with `SmtpClient.Value`. This gives you a new `ISmtpClient` object on each line.

You need to construct the `Lazy<T>` object just once, and return that in the Property's getter, as in Daniels code. The property's type should be the type you want to use (i.e. you don't expose a `Lazy<T>` type to the consumer).