# Should lazy property return Value or Lazy(of Value)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, lazy-initialization

I have a lazy property with value constructed at the first access time:

```
private readonly ValueLazy as Lazy(of integer)

public readony property Value as integer
    get
        return ValueLazy.Value
    end get
end property

public sub new(Service as IService)
    me.ValueLazy = new Lazy(of integer)(function() Service.GetInteger)
end sub
```

Since actual value is requested from `Service`, it may take some time to construct property value. This seems to violate rule that property getter should be fast and do minimum work.

Should property really return value (e.g. `Integer`)?

Or should property instead return lazy of value (e.g. `Lazy(of Integer)`)?

```
public readony property Value as Lazy(of integer)
    get
        return ValueLazy
    end get
end property
```

Comment: Apparently you [should return the value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730696/11683).

Comment: @GSerg They do say that "_when using Lazy<T> you expose a property of the actual type_" and "_the property's type should be the type you want to use (i.e. you don't expose a Lazy<T> type to the consumer)_", but I'd like to hear the reasoning behind this statement and how it works when value initiation time is long.